# Tupel of lineary independent linear forms gives a surjection

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional $K$-vector space of dimension $n$ and $(\phi_1,...,\phi_r)$ lineary independent elements of $V^\ast$.

Considering the map $f=(\phi_1,...,\phi_r):V\to K^r$, the kernel of $f$ turns out to be the intersection of the kernels of the $\phi_i$'s. But is $f$ surjektive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. By the rank-nullity theorem$$\dim\operatorname{Im}F=n-\dim\ker f=n-(n-r)=r=\dim K^r.$$Therefore, $\operatorname{Im}F=K^r$.

---

Here's another proof. Since $V$ has dimension $n$, you can assume without loss of generality that $V=K^n$. Suppose that $f$ is *not* surjective. Then there are scalars $a_1,\ldots,a_n$, not all of which are $0$, such that$$\operatorname{Im}F\subset\left\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in K^r\,\middle|\,\sum_{k=1}^ra_kx_k=0\right\},$$since $\operatorname{Im}F\neq K^r$ and therefore $\operatorname{Im}F$ is contained in some hyperplane. But then$$\bigl(\forall(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in K^r\bigr):\sum_{k=1}^ra_k\phi_k(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=0.$$In other words, $\sum_{k=1}^ra_k\phi_k=0$, which is impossible, since the $\phi_k$'s are linearly independent.

Comment: I am asking this question because if the answer were 'yes' it helps proving $\dim\text{ker}(f)=n-r$. So an answer which doesn't use this fact would be nice. But thanks anyway!

Comment: It would have been nice if you had provided that piece of information within the original question.

Comment: I know, I am sorry.

Comment: I've added another answer.

Comment: Thank you! What do you mean by $\phi_k(x_1,...,x_n)$ and why are there such $a_i$'s?

Comment: I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is surjective,  since given $(x_1,\dots,x_r)\in K^r$, take $a_i=\frac {x_i}{\phi_i(1)}$.  Then $f(a_1,\dots,a_r)=(a_1\phi_1(1),\dots,a_r\phi_r(1))=(x_1,\dots, x_r)$.  Note: $\phi_i(1)\not=0 \;\forall i$, by linear independence...